# Does semantic UI progressbar work without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

Does [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com) work without JavaScript? I want to display the **language and level of proficiency** as a progress bar on a page, but I don't need the value to change while the page is loaded --   there is no need to apply dynamic values. The progress level will be known when the page is loaded.

As you can see below, I am not getting the desired output. I expect to see 75% progress (15/20), and that's not what I'm getting:

**html file**

```
    <div class="ui teal progress" data-value="15" data-total="20">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Minor edits for legibility, plus link to Semantic UI.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Semantic UI requires that you initialize all progress bars through its jQuery extension:

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html#/usage

You can see from the first example that, until you click on `Run Code`, the progress bar looks exactly like how yours does in the screenshot. However, if you don't need the progress bar to move/animate and you have full control of the CSS, you can just set a `width` on the `div.bar` element:

```
.bar { width: 65% }
```

Comment: I would be calling the value from the database. so CSS is not the option.

Comment: `<div class="ui teal progress" data-percent="74" id="lang_val">
        <div class="bar"></div>
</div>`
so here i will have to declare the max val in javascript and the user value inside html right?

Comment: How are you setting the value `74`?

Comment: it will come from the database. for now i am just templating.

Comment: Then you can change it from `data-percent="74"` in the `<div class="ui teal progress>` to `<div class="bar" style="width: 74%">`. But honestly, if you're using Semantic UI, you basically **need** to use jQuery and its JS scripts. Otherwise the library is severely gimped without it.